# Find and copy the two most recent files added to a directory with a specific format

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, hp-ux

I'm currently writing a ksh script that will run every 5 minutes. I want to **select the two most recently added files within a directory** that have a specific format. The format of the file should be: `OUS_*_*_*.html`. The files should then be copied over to a destination directory.

I assume I can use find, but I am using HP-UX and it does not support the `-amin`, `-cmin`, `-mmin` options. Does anyone know how I can achieve this functionality?

**Edit 1:** I have found the following commands, each of which are supposed to return the single newest file, but in use more than one file is listed:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
ls -t | head -n1
```

**Edit 2:** I can see how the functionality of these commands should work, but `ls -t` lists files in a table format, and selecting the first line actually selects three separate file names. I attempted to use `ls -lt`, but now the first line is a string `total 112` followed by the file names along with their access rights, time stamp, etc..

**Edit 3:** I found that the `-1` (numeral 1, not l) option provides a list with just file names. Using the command `ls -1t | head -n 2` I was able to gain the ability to list the two newest files.

**Q:** Is it possible to restrict the `ls` command to just look for files with the previously mentioned format?

Comment: Even in the worst case, using `ls -t | head -2` comes to mind. Surely that is available on HP-UX?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Those commands are available, however when running the commands in  a test directory 6 out of a total of 8 files are listed. @JosephMyers

Comment: @JosephMyers Would you be able to extend your command to list and copy the two most recent files that fit a specific format?

Comment: I would like to, but I only provide answers that I know that will work. I am not familiar with the HP-UX environment, only many other Unix and Linux variants. If I were on the Debian/Ubuntu branch of Linux, for example, I would use `ls -t | head -2 | xargs cp -it TargetDir` and be done with it. But the `-t` flag isn't available on FreeBSD, for instance. And `xargs` itself might not even be on HP-UX for all I know. Even the syntax of `head` and `tail` are different on your system. So use the example I mentioned and see if you can work with it. If you solve it, you can write the answer!

Comment: Well, actually, since you are only using two files, and assuming they don't have any dangerous characters nor whitespace, you can using tick marks for expansion, which should be cross-platform (but might  not! I don't k now HP-UX). `cp -i \`ls -1t | head -n 2\` TargetDirectory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this block of code to list the most recently added files to a directory that conform to a specific format:

```
ls -1t $fileNameFormat | head -n 2
```